# How to change picture box image dynamically at runtime

Tags: c#

I have a problem to **display images in picture box from my database that have to change dynamically at runtime under some conditions** .

I want step by step process explanation for my problem.
Kindly help me!

Have a good day!

Comment: vague question. 'from my database' what database 'under some conditions' what conditions

Answer (score 1):

Is it a push or pull model?
pull:
Create a timer with a certain time, when the time event fires, connect to database, retrieve picture and set picturebox.Image

Comment: Actually it is the sql database ,the conditions is the pull method that it  should change the picture for every 10 seconds.and i need the detailde code using c#.Please help me as soon as possible.

Thank You


Suba291

Comment: Well create some code to pull data from a SQL database. Call it with a timer. First try it out yourself. If it won't work, post some code. Where not here to create code for you, but help your problems.